# Apns Delegate Never Fired Occurs and why i need to switch on off my network and wifi

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I'm Building OneSignal Push Notification in ios App:
 here is my OneSignal Initialization code:

```
    let oneSignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false,
                                 kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: true]

    OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
                                    appId: AUTHKeys.ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID,
                                    handleNotificationReceived: nil,
                                    handleNotificationAction: notificationOpenedBlock,
                                    settings: oneSignalInitSettings)

    OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification
```

in Some devices showing **Apns Delegate Never Fired**  and **Other Apns 3000 Error**

I have tried many slution but not found any better way to resolve this error.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Still facing this issue sometimes due to wifi or internet connections

Comment: I too can confirm that it has something to do with internet connection. It works fine with wifi but when i switch to lte network it gets push_token : null

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late for you.

But I have found that when testing apps in development mode on IOS 13 iPads, that the Apns Delegate Never Fired issue can be related to your DNS.

To test, change your DNS to use Google's DNS servers 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4

This resolves the issue for me, I hope that it is useful

Comment: I'm currently trying to add OneSignal in my app, and I have this `Apns Delegate Never Fired` error from time to time. sometime when doing wifi, sometime with 4g(lte in us ?). it usually works with wifi. From what I read, it' s because it's using the sandbox push servers, and they are somewhat "not great". But I did a TestFlight, which from what I read should use the production apns, and I still got `Apns Delegate Never Fired` with some iPhones. is it only a development only problem, and I shouldn't worry because the App Store will not have these problems, or should I try to fix that ?

Comment: I think you have no need to worry. it's an internet issue and work on wifi smothly

Answer (score 0):

if you use version 'OneSignal', '>= 2.11.2', '< 3.0' try to use this version 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'

Comment: OneSignal Surly provides many fixes in the latest version can you please tell me why I use this version.